# first order discount in magento2

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

tried below script but it is not applied discount for first Order. Any suggestions?

[Magento 2: How to implement First Order Discount?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213903/magento-2-how-to-implement-first-order-discount)

Answer (score 0):

My requirement was to apply the discount on the first three orders. I have achieved this by creating a promotional rule. Cart Price Rule is the best way.No Need of coding here.
Please check the attached screesnhot[image].