# Magento2 Product discount by customer attribute

Tags: magento2.3, discount

I am using Magento2.3.1.
I need to discount a product by a customer custom attribute.
I've added "DynamoCustomerType" to customer attribute.
I used [this first order discount tutorial](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213903/magento-2-how-to-implement-first-order-discount) to add customer attribute to cart price rule condition.
It works perfectly for cart price rule.[Here's a screenshot.](https://screencast.com/t/RIVJGUecdk)
I need this work the same for catalog price rule.
Please let me know how to add a custom option to catalog price rule conditions and connect an event to it.
Thanks.